# C++ compiler parse the templates before instantiation? why?

Tags: c++, templates

It appears to me C++ compiler parses the templates even before it is instantiated. Otherwise this does not explain the use of keyword typename for declaring a dependent name as a type. In another words, if compiler parse the template definition only when it is instantiated, I don't think there is ambiguity for interpreting

```
template < typename Foo >
struct ABC {
    Foo::iterator * i;
}
```

Hence typename is not needed before Foo::iterator.

Therefore, I think compiler parses the definition before it is instantiated (type Foo is known). The question is, why it does this? Why not delay until it is instantiated and all types are known.

Comment: The question is "which compiler". But in general this is a good read on the topic: http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html  and this on the "why" part: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates

Comment: What you're describing sounds like preprocessor macros. I think many people are glad that templates provide a somewhat more powerful abstraction.

Comment: @PeterT: That article covers "why" phase 2 is needed, but the question is why phase 1 exists at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It appears to me C++ compiler parses the templates even before it is instantiated.

That's its job. It's a compiler, not a macro processor.

> if compiler parse the template definition only when it is instantiated, I don't think there is ambiguity for interpreting

One problem with that is that errors in the template itself won't be detected as long as it is only instantiated with 'friendly' types that don't trigger the errors: for example, if the template assumes that the type always has such-and-such a method.

Comment: Templates can certainly choose to assume that their type parameters always have some method--the problem with fully-deferred parsing (like MSVC has used for a long time) is that the template may mean different things based on whether the members of its parameters are **types**, templates, or neither.

Answer (score 0):

CRTP would be an issue otherwise. In short, this is legal:

```
template <typename T> struct Base { };
struct Derived : Base<Derived> { };
```

Clearly, if `Base<Derived>` could only be compiled once `Derived` was compiled, we'd have an issue because `Derived` can only be compiled once `Base<Derived>` is compiled. Phase 1 compilation of `Base<T>` is however sufficient to compile `Derived`.